# How to access an element of a nested array without using map in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I need to access a specific element from an object that I have nested within an array, I'm using react functional components.

```
 const accordionItems = [
    { id: 'Releases',
     items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3} ]
    },
    
    { id: 'Radio',
      items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3} ]
    },

    { id: 'Contact',
      items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3} ]
    }
  ];
```

That is the code where my objects are stored. I need to access the 'data' of each one specifically to feed to a parameter of an audio player.

My attempt to do this is below:

```
   <AudioPlayer 
      src={accordionItems[1].items.data[1]}
   />
```

I followed the syntax that I researched from a few other questions on here but it seems to send the error of:

```
Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

To my knowledge accordionItems holds three objects which can be accessed through accordionItems[x] and from there you enter the items array and note which data point is to be fed to the source of the audio player.

Does anyone have a solution to help me access this specific data point? Most of the answers that I've researched involved using the map function which I don't think will be appropriate in the long term for how I'm aiming to build this application.

Thanks!

Comment: With `accordionItems[1].items.data`  you will get the whole `data` prop. If that prop is an array access it like you did, but seems is not an array or it's undefined. If it's an object access its props with `accordionItems[1].items.data['property']`

Comment: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined is what is returns when making the amendment which seems to be some variant on the original problem

Comment: What's the type of tracks variables? Are they defined?

Comment: `accordionItems[1].items[1].data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue here is the way you access the data in the actual array.

Let's destructure your query: `accordionItems[1].items.data[1]`

First of all, `accordionItems[1]` is correct because `accordionItems` is an array and you can just pick element `1` out of it.

They you access `items`, which is fine as well, but you can't take `data` from `items` like that since `items` is an array.

What you want as a final result is `accordionItems[1].items[1].data`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `accordionItems` might be changing with time, like it might be initialised to an empty state or the number of items might be changing dynamically (if you could add more code to show what you are doing).

I am not sure what your logic is, but you can always create logic to show items where you are not hard-coding the `index`. `map` is a very handy function in many use-cases, maybe it doesn't suit yours. As an example, you can consider something like below, if it helps.

```js
const accordionItems = [
  {
    id: 'Releases',
    items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3}
    ]
  },
  { 
    id: 'Radio',
    items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3}
    ]
  },
  { 
    id: 'Contact',
    items: [
      {item: '123 / first show / 14/3/19', data: track1}, 
      {item: '456 /second show / 31/3/19', data: track2}, 
      {item: '789 / third show / 7/4/19', data: track3} 
    ]
  }
];

const getTrack = (options, type) => {
  const typeItem = options.find((item) => item.id === type);
  if(typeItem && typeItem.items && typeItems.length > 0) {
    // whatever logic you have to extract the track
    // you can use find or filter and similar functions
  }
  return null;
}

const Player = () => {
  // replace radio by anything else or you can even make it state/prop based
  const trackSource = getTrack(accordionItems, "radio");
  return (
   <>
     {
       trackSource ? <AudioPlayer src={trackSource} /> : <SourceDoesNotExist />;
     }
   </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<AudioPlayer 
      src={accordionItems[1].items.data[1]}
   />
```

should be

```js
<AudioPlayer 
      src={accordionItems[1].items[1].data}
   />
```

because items are an array, not data.